# Fetch all the accounts from large account hierarchy

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to fetch all the accounts from account hierarchy from all the levels, code should work for any number of levels.

for example : If there is a account hierarchy then using any of the account inside the hierarchy, I should be able to find all accounts inside account hierarchy.

```
            Account 1
           /         \
    Account 2      Account3
```

Answer should be : [Account 1, Account 2, Account3] (Ordered by parent id)

This is my code to get All the Accounts from that is there inside a particular hierarchy

```apex
public class SK_AccountTreeGridCmpController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> findHierarchyData(string recId){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        string queryString = 'select id,name,type,industry,parentId from Account ';
        //Section to get all child account details from ultimate parent starts-------------------------
        List<String> currentParent      = new List<String>{};
        Integer level               = 0;
        Boolean endOfStructure      = false;
        //method to find ultimate parent of account
        string topMostparent = GetUltimateParentId(recId );
        system.debug('*******topMostparent:'+topMostparent);
        currentParent.add(topMostparent);
        system.debug('**********topMostparent:'+ currentParent);
        //Loop though all children
        string finalQueryString = '';
        List<Account>  queryOutput = new List<Account> ();
        while ( !endOfStructure ){  
            if( level == 0 ){
                finalQueryString = queryString + ' where id IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY ParentId  Limit 1000';
            } 
            else {
                finalQueryString = queryString + ' where ParentID IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY ParentId Limit 1000';
            }
            system.debug('********finalQueryString:'+finalQueryString);
            if(finalQueryString != null && finalQueryString !=''){
                try{
                    if(Limits.getLimitQueries()-Limits.getQueries()>0){
                        queryOutput = database.query(finalQueryString);
                        system.debug('***hierarchy level:'+level);
                    }else{
                        system.debug('****endOfStructure is true as SOQL limit reaches:');
                        endOfStructure = true;
                    }
                }catch(exception ex){ 
                    endOfStructure = true;
                }
            }
            system.debug('**queryOutput size:'+queryOutput);
            if( queryOutput.size() == 0 ){
                endOfStructure = true;
            }
            else{
                currentParent.clear();
                //iterating through query output
                for ( Integer i = 0 ; i < queryOutput.size(); i++ ){
                    currentParent.add(queryOutput[i].Id);
                    accList.add(queryOutput[i]);
                }
            }
            level++;
        }
        system.debug('**********accList:'+accList);
        return accList;
    }
    
    // Find the tom most element in Heirarchy  
    // @return objId
    public static String GetUltimateParentId( string recId ){
        Boolean top = false;
        while ( !top ) {
            string queryString = 'select id ,name, ParentId from Account where Id =:recId LIMIT 1';
            Account acc = database.query(queryString);
            if ( acc.parentId != null ) {
                recId = acc.parentId;
            }else {
                top = true;
            }
        }
        return recId ;
    }
}
```

But this code is not efficient, I'm not able to get accounts if Hierarchy is very big.

Please provide an efficient solution where I can get all the Accounts even if the Hierarchy is very big.

Thanks

Comment: SOQL allows you to traverse 5 layers in related objects, but actually only one layer down with related lists. Because you want to support arbitrary depths, which likely could be more than 5 levels deep, you fundamentally cannot do it in one SOQL. Indeed, it is fair to say you cannot actually solve your requirement in general terms since you are restricted to 100 queries in a given session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any good answer here unfortunately. Your best bet is probably going to be creating a field called "Top-Level Parent" that you can use with SOQL. Since you can't to do a rollup multiple layers deep, you'll have to use a flow/apex to automatically populate the new field whenever the Parent is modified on an account. The tricky part here is going to be handling all children whenever a parent is updated. For example, if Parent 1 owns Child 2, and Child 2 owns Grandchild 3 and Grandchild 4, if Child 2's parent is updated, you'll also have to update the Grandchildren to match.

Once this is in place, you'll have to backfill all existing "Top-Level Parent" fields which is going to involve some Excel vlookup dirty magic that populates the corresponding columns with Parent 1, Parent 2, etc, then use a final column to find the highest hierarchy in the sequence to use as the Top Level Parent.

Hopefully this is enough to get you off the ground, but let me know if you have any further questions or clarification.